# How to set custom list's column order declaratively

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, custom-list, column, ordering

So basically what I want to achieve is to find a way to set column order on my custom lists declaratively (I'm using list definitions to create my custom Lists).

1. One way of setting column order is to go to List Settings and set column order on the list (via browser).
2. Another way is to use code (possibly feature activated event) and set column order by the code.

The problem with first approach is that, there are many lists, and I don't want to go and set column order after each deployment.

Second approach, setting column order programmatically seems to me redundant.

Besides, if there is a way to change column order via browser, SharePoint should save this order somewhere, so that makes me think/hope there is a way to set the order declaratively.

Unfortunately googling around didn't help, so any hint/help would be greatly appreciated.
And I'm using SharePoint 2013.